# How to allow admin to change anyone's password in Membership

Tags: asp.net, membership

How does the default ASP.NET Membership's **Change Password** page allow me to change *anyone's* password? It looks like the Change Password page doesn't take any parameters where I could specify User ID or something. It appear like it is designed to change the password of currently logged in user only. Or is there a way around it?

Comment: a good way to start : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.changepassword.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The default functionality does not allow you to do that. You must supply the "old password".

If you must provide this possibility (instead of letting users reset their password via the password answer), I'm afraid you must implement it yourself.

Comment: I can get the old password from the DB (i'm storing them as plain text in the database). Do I still stand a chance?

Comment: Give it a try then! I strongly advise you not to store plain text passwords, though.